# How to vectorize for loop with custom index

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I'm new to Matlab, so I'm not sure if this is possible. I have a simple for-loop:

```
for i=1:n
    B.x(indexB(i)) += A.x(i);
end
```

Where A.x and B.x are two vectors of length n, and indexB is a vector of length n that contains the appropriate mapping from elements in A.x to B.x.

Is it possible to vectorize this loop?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think so, following this example:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5];
b = a;
idx = [5 4 3 2 1];
a(idx)  = a(idx) + b(1:5);
```

Which should give:

```
a =

 6     6     6     6     6
```

So in your case, if `indexB` has size `n` you can write:

```
B.x(indexB) = B.x(indexB) + A.x(1:n);
```

And otherwise:

```
B.x(indexB(1:n)) = B.x(indexB(1:n)) + A.x(1:n);
```

Comment: Would this still work if both A and B were not the same length?

Comment: Yes, but there has to be an one-to-one mapping between the indices left and right, or in this case, the index vector `indexB` used for B.x and the index vector `[1:n]` used for A.x. And obviously, the elements the indices refer to, need to exist.